# WCF Web Service - My service configuration says HTTPS, my client says HTTP

Tags: wcf, web-services, https

My WCF Service implementation *appears* to have all necessary HTTPS configuration settings. The whole client-> service comms work just fine, my issue is that request responses do not appear to be transported over HTTPS.

My configuration:

wsHttpBinding - check 
mexHttpsBinding - check 
security mode="Message"  - check 
httpsGetEnabled - check

When I examined the comms in Fiddler then I see the request and response being made over HTTP rather than HTTPS. This ties up with the WSDL action which states:



`location="http://ws019.sms.com/Alpha.Services.AMSB2B/DeviceService.svc/Journey"/
wsa10:Address
http://ws019.sms.com/Alpha.Services.AMSB2B/DeviceService.svc/Journey
/wsa10:Address`



Also in my endpoint configuration on the client side, the endpoint is pointing at the HTTP address rather than the HTTPS address (presumably this is looking at the WSDL) eg.



`endpoint address="http://ws019.sms.com/Alpha.Services.AMSB2B/DeviceService.svc/Device"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDeviceService" 
        contract="AMSB2B.IDeviceService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDeviceService"`

Why does the WSDL / client endpoint address have HTTP in there, rather than HTTPS? If I change the configuration manually, it complains at runtime about expecting HTTP.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong. WsHttpBinding with Message security uses HTTP. You must use Transport security.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to use Message security, it's a public access API and from my understanding it's preferable to use Message mode security over transport in such a scenario. Does this mean the encrypted data is always sent over HTTP when using Message mode security?

Comment: In that case you don't need HTTPs. Why would you encrypt and sign your messages twice? Builtin WsHttpBinding always uses HTTP channel when message security is used, because encryption and signing is performed on message level.

Comment: Thanks again -  I ended up creating a second endpoint on the service that used Transport security and it worked a treat.